# How change new unified Grafana alerting labels keyID to custom legend or the displayed legend name on the panel

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts, grafana-templating

I am using new Grafana alerting.
I am facing that when alert is fired, the legend name that i have configured on the query in not taken on alert notification like in the old Grafana alerting.

It will always take the series name

Is there a way to retrieve the original legend name like on the displayed panel or from my custom legend or how to do transformation style on alerting as "TRANSFORM DATA" does

my exemple :
the original series name : **{instance="localhost:9100"}**
[the original series name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yykmX.png)

What **I want to have** in notification is : **Total CPU Usage**
[What I want to have in notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK0CL.png)

I have configured a code following this link: [Templating labels and annotations | Grafana documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/fundamentals/annotation-label/variables-label-annotation/)

My code:

```
{{ range $v := $values -}}
{{ $v.Labels }}={{ humanize ($v.Value) }}%
{{ end }}
```

[Summary code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jHoo.png)

But in mail notification, the default legend name in **Value** is always key ID, and in **Summary** it's not changed to the display on the panel
[mail notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcwjn.png)